# Error with my build.gradle file in android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, build.gradle

I have an error with my build.gradle file in Android Studio. It is complaining about `Properties` and recommends creating a `Properties` Class.

[image]

Comment: can you try to invalidate cache and rebuild?

Comment: Why do you set variables in the beginning, not after `apply plugin: ...`? I think, plugins should stand at first positions.

Answer (score 0):

have you set your project structuve level the Java SDK? You can find it under File >> Project Structure (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S) Like this:

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S9y4.png)

The error on GradleExcpetion is normal though.

Hope it helps!